Is it bad to pass builders as constructor arguments?
Note. It's a "spin-off" from my previous question. Not a duplicate — it focuses on a different topic
I got to know builders from Bloch's Effective Java. However, I made two changes to his design

(no biggie) I added a static accessor for the nested builder. Since the builder still has to be public, direct referencing is still possible

(yes biggie?) Made the buildable class's only (private) constructor accept its own builder and nothing else. That way, I would avoid a big parameter list. Since builders are typically used when there are multiple parameters to pass, it's a feel-good change that allows me to neatly pass this in the build() method and decompose the builder later in the constructor


Some say, it turns my builder into a service locator which is a known anti-pattern. They argue it hides the class's actual dependencies. I don't see a problem with this as the constructor is not part the class's API, so the only party it may be be "hiding" anything from is its nested builder, the constructor's only client
So what do you think?

Does that change really turn my builder into a service locator?
More broadly, is what I did bad?

public class MyClass {
    private final String someArg;
    // other fields

    private MyClass(Builder builder) {
        this.someArg = builder.someArg;
        // ...
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    // business logic
    
    public static class Builder {
        private String someArg;

        public Builder setSomeArg(String someArg) {
            this.someArg = someArg;
            return this;
        }

        // other setters

        public MyClass build() {
            return new MyClass(this);
        }

// some instantiating client
    MyClass.builder()
        .setSomeArg(someArg)
        // other setters if necessary
        .build();

UPD: Hm, it seems Bloch also passed this in the build() (instead of decomposing the builder and passing "real" args), so item 2 is not a design change after all. It's strange, 'cause I remember it differently. I wonder whether my memory is failing me or it changed between different editions of the book (probably, the former)

This was already answered in the previous question that this is a service locator pattern, in the highest upvoted answer, and your response to it was "I don't believe it's a service locator". Nothing about this new question changes any of the given information. "I don't see a problem with this" is not a meaningful contribution, especially since your "constructor is not API" argument completely misses that the service locator antipattern guideline inherently focuses on badly designed constructors.

@Flater "This was already answered in the previous question that this is a service locator pattern, in the highest upvoted answer, and your response to it was 'I don't believe it's a service locator'" Actually, Greg Burghardt said so before my edits that added the builder code. Afterwards, he said the point was invalidated. The other user, Basilevs, disagreed, though

@Flater at any rate, this question focuses on a different topic, clearly not a duplicate

Greg recanting their judgment on the service locator antipattern is a valid thing to mention (why they kept it in the answer then is beyond me) but at the end of the day it's still a service locator. This question isn't on a different topic, it's the same persisted antipattern. As per your own words: "Builders address that. A buildable class has only one declared dependency – on its builder." is an act of semantical acrobatics as you're trying to use naming to dodge the underlying issues with the service locator antipattern (spoiler alert: the issue isn't the name being used).

[..] If you assert that you need a builder, and the builder's responsibility is to construct the buildable object, then the builder needs to be comfortable being aware of what is needed to construct the object. What you're doing here is the same as anyone who resorts to service locators: "I don't like writing many parameters so I'll instead write one big bag of parameters". The consequence is that now MyThing's constructor is roped into doing the builder's work for it, defeating the purpose of properly separating the two, in the pursuit of not typing out the params you concretely need.

@Flater I didn't realize that change was such a big deal. The constructor is private. "Hiding" anything from a nested class, the constructor's only client, is impossible anyway in Java. I guess you could say I merged two patterns, builder and parameter object, but I am still not convinced service locator has anything to do with it

If you had read up on the service locator antipattern and looked for the underlying issue that it highlights, which is not related to the nature of the injected matter being a service (vs it being a value like for your builder), but rather that a locator acts as a bag of smuggled goodies with no real accountability for the individual goodies in the bag; you would've understood why that change is such a big deal. You now again doubling down in your last comment that you don't think service locators have anything to do with it suggests you're not really interested in hearing the answer.

It's not about "hiding" in the sense of "making invisible". It's about "hiding" in the sense of muddying what would otherwise be a clear record of required input. There's no hard and fast rule here because it requires nuance and context. You you shouldn't break every param down to primitives, and you should throw all of it in a single bag either. Both extremes are bad. This requires contextual consideration of what is a meaningful expression of a constructor's parameters.

@Flater what exactly do you mean by "real accountability for the individual goodies"?

@Flater also, why do you call it a service locator, not a parameter object?

There's only so many way I can get you to read the established literature on the service locator antipattern. It answers every question you have asked since your previous post. I'm not interested in explaining the thing that you keep rejecting, by having me pretend it's actually totally different advice, which it is not. If you want to assert that your situation is unique and not bother learning from existing guidelines, you do you. I maintain that your question was asked and answered before you posted this follow up question.

Sorry, but why is #2 a "design change"? According to https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/exploring-joshua-blochs-builder-design-pattern-in-java  , this is exactly how Bloch's builder pattern is typically implemented. What am I missing?

I think we should not focus on exact term here. The interesting part of the question is - is service locator explicitly exposing dependencies still an antipattern?

@DocBrown oh. It's no longer available in Open Library, so I can't check. But as far as I recall, he didn't pass builders to constructors, he decomposed his builders in the build() method

@Flater what do you mean by "established literature"? The only established literature on OOP patterns that I know of is Design Patterns by the Gang of Four, and no service locator is on their list. I figured it's a relatively novel term

@SergeyZolotarev: does it really matter what Bloch originally wrote? It seems your suggestion is already widely used. So "passing builders as constructor arguments" seems to be pretty standard.

The point of a builder is to prevent creation of "unfinished" objects. You are just defining a new way to create an unfinished instance of MyClass.

You should read up on the service locator pattern. Understanding that pattern will answer this question.

@SergeyZolotarev: I found Bloch's original NutritionFact example in the Web, see my answer below.

@DocBrown yeah, you're right, he did pass this too. Well then, since I take words of people like Joshua Bloch, Bob Martin, Martin Fowler (the great ones) as pure gold, I figure I am redeemed and can keep implementing my builder that way (unless Bloch changes his mind in a new edition of Effective Java)

I take words of people like [...] as pure gold - these guys are not priests, and I think noone should take their writings as dogma. Not that they haven't published several good ideas and "brain food", but I would take all their writings with a grain of salt (especially those of Bob Martin), use from them what works under pragmatic aspects, and ignore the rest.

I am not going into this Service Locator debate, but looking at Bloch's original example, which I found here, it seems your "design change" isn't one. Passing the builder as a constructor parameter to the builded class' private constructor was exactly Bloch's suggestion.
The only change which remains is the extra static builder() method, but this is more a matter of taste, since
MyClass.builder();

saves only a few characters of typing when compared to
new MyClass.Builder();

and that's all it does.
So whatever you showed us here, I think it is not better or worse than Bloch's original Builder pattern, because it is simply the same.

A builder is supposed to create an instance of A or a subclass of A. Your pattern prevents that. Especially the builder may be defined to return an instance of a subclass of some abstract class A.
What a builder should do: 1. Examine its arguments. 2. Based on the arguments, decide which class to build an instance of. 3. Based on the arguments, create an instance of the class it chose and call its constructor with these arguments. The constructor of the instance that is created should have no knowledge of the builder at all.
The rule that a constructor shouldn’t have many arguments is because many arguments make it possible that 99 constructor calls are correct, and the 100th contains a stupid bug passing the wrong argument. Your builder class has only one constructor call, so that argument goes away.

Wait. But it's also the case with Bloch's unaltered version

@SergeyZolotarev: Are you implying that Bloch's original example is flawless and beyond reproach? gnasher's feedback here is actively arguing against that approach, on the merit of the deconstruction of that builder into the constituent constructor parameters needing to be a responsibility of the builder, not a responsibility of the object's constructor. It diffuses the responsibility of the builder into two separate locations (the builder class, and the buildable object constructor), with no real benefit here other than not having needed to write down all the constructor params.

Seems like we are voting on this :)

Yeah I think it's like a service locator. Essentially you have the same pattern

...
builder.AddDependency(someDependency)

myclass(Builder b)
{
    dependency = b.FindDependency();
}

vs
diContainer.AddDependency(someDependency)

myclass(DiContainer c)
{
    dependency = c.FindDependency();
}


Yeah I think it's bad.


You couple the two classes so you can't add different builders or subclasses without jumping through hoops
Users can't not use the builder, say for example it doesn't play well with their DI framework
You could just make a normal builder without adding these problems, there would be no downside
You could just override constructors to get around your feelings about needing a builder anyway
You have to use nested classes to get the private stuff working

I'm not a fan of builders, they can be cool if you have some extremely complex setup and you enforce all the methods through clever interfaces. But it's a lot of work for very little gain. They aren't needed just because you have a lot of construction parameters and they dont help reduce the construction parameters.
You don't seem to have some compelling problem which is improved by this solution, people will find it easier if you just do things the "normal way" rather than having to work out your builder.
Having said that, if the "normal" way is to use an Options constructor, then fill your boots
myclass = new MyClass(o=> o.UseDependency(someDependency));

I think this fails for the same reasons, but it seems popular these days.

Thank you. Why is it not a parameter object?

it might also be a parameter object! do you want to make a new question about whether those are also bad and if they solve your problem?

So why is it a parameter object and a service locator, in your opinion? Why not just the former?

I think your issue is that you are attempting to make logical arguments based on the premise that A or B is "good" and therefore if X can be argued meets the definition of A or B it must also be good. But this isn't really the case. A and B aren't rigorously defined, there is no agreement on if they are good or not, and small differences can have big effects.

you can only look at the up and down sides of a given approach and come to some conclusion. I think on your other question people have already pointed out that many construction parameters is prob a symptom of an overly big object with too many responsibilities. Adding more code to try and make it pretty isnt goign to solve anything

Hence, the first sentence in my answer to your other question, @SergeyZolotarev.
